# Differences of grade between this three books

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a simple question, I noticed these three books for my study, but I didn't understand the grade of these books because the names of the paragraphs are similar .

1) [http://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Its-Applications-Edition/dp/0321385179/ref=dp_ob_title_bk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321385179) ( high school/undergraduate )

2) [http://www.amazon.com/dp/0471751561](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471751561) ( undergraduate/graduate)

3) Linear Algebra and Its Applications, 4th Edition - Gilbert Strang ( graduate text that tell about high linear algebra or advanced linear algebra )

Does anyone can confermate this order ?

( I'm not english )

Comment: Gilbert Strang's book is an early undergraduate level (first or second year university) textbook. The others appear to be at that level, too.

Comment: Mmm ... What's a text I can use for advanced algebra or abstract algebra ? I found these : Algebra ( 2nd Edition, Featured Titles for Abstract Algebra ) Michael Artin, Representation Theory: A First Course ( Graduate Texts in Mathematics / Readings in Mathematics ) William Fulton, Algebra ( Graduate Texts in Mathematics ) Serge Lang . I should follow in this order ?